# Ref Cursor and regular curso

Tags: sql, plsql

hello i am trying to pass the output of a ref_curs (variables) to a cursor declared in the declare part of the procedure.

```
declare
  v_deptno  number; 
  v_name  number ;
  v_number;

  c1 ref_cursor;

  c2   (v_deptno VARCHAR2) select empno,ename from emp ;
                             where depto = v_deptno;
begin
  open c1 for select deptno from emp; 

  loop
    fetch c1 into v_deptno
    exit when c1%notfound;
  end loop;

  if v_deptno not null then 
    open c2

    fetch c2 into v_name,v_number
  end loop;

  end if;
end;
```

here is my issue . trying ot pass the deptno to c2

Comment: Your code won't compile which is somewhat troubling, but never mind - to pass `deptno` to cursor c2 you'd want to say something like `OPEN C2(v_deptno);`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: the problem i have is the ref_cursor i get the value in the deptono but not sure why i am unable to pass it  c2 but will try your method and see if thats work. thanks